# Huge continuity error in Top Gun Maverick?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun-maverick

In the very opening scene in Top Gun Maverick, Maverick rides his Motorcycle to the Air Force base where the mach 10 airplane is being held. When he does this, the sun is high in the sky and a few minutes later, it is morning and the sun is just rising. Is there something I missed, or is this really just a huge continuity error?

Answer (score 10):

> When he does this, the sun is high in the sky and a few minutes later, it is morning and the sun is just rising.

You seem to be missing the point that there is a montage of Maverick preparing for the test flight all afternoon and through the night before the experimental aircraft takes off just at dawn.

Indeed we see the aircraft start it's engines while it's dark.

[image]